Sefaradim poskim and edot
With which edah among sefaradim is associated these poskim and what is the place of Kabbalah in their psakim :

Maran Rav Ovadia Yossef zl
Maran Mordekhai Eliyahu zl
HaRav Shalom Messas zl
HaRav Ben Tsion Abba Shaul zl
HaRav David Halevy zl and
Rav Meir Uziel Ben Tsion zl


WIKI should probably answer the first part of your question.

Ok so : - Edot haMizrach : rav Ovadia Yosef, Rav Mordechai Eliyahou, Rav Bakshi Doron and Rav Ben Tsion Abba Chaoul ; Edot haMaarav : Rav Shalom Messas, , rav Halevy and Rav Meir Uziel Ben Zion. Is it right? And for the second part of the question?
